# Why does it take three Full GC to garbage collect permgen?

Tags: garbage-collection, java-7, permgen

What are the reasons why it would take three successive "Full GC" before perm gen is garbage collected?

The first GC got the heap down from 2.4gb to 761mb, but fails to substantially GC perm gen, though it does appear to recover 6K.

We'll ignore the young generation collection.

The second Full GC does very little for the heap, as expected since the server was lightly loaded at the time. The odd thing is that it did NOTHING for perm gen.

The third Full GC finally takes perm gen from its max of 524mb down to 141mb.

Here's the unedited snippet from the GC logs:

```
2012-12-07T19:46:40.731-0600: [Full GC [CMS: 2474402K->761372K(2804992K), 4.6386780 secs]     2606228K->761372K(3111680K), [CMS Perm : 524286K->524280K(524288K)], 4.6387670 secs] [Times: user=4.68 sys=0.00, real=4.63 secs] 
2012-12-07T19:46:45.374-0600: [GC [ParNew
Desired survivor size 17432576 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:      65976 bytes,      65976 total
: 1552K->8827K(306688K), 0.0199700 secs] 762925K->770200K(3111680K), 0.0200340 secs]  [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2012-12-07T19:46:45.395-0600: [Full GC [CMS: 761372K->752917K(2804992K), 3.7379280 secs]  770212K->752917K(3111680K), [CMS Perm : 524287K->524287K(524288K)], 3.7380180 secs] [Times: user=3.77 sys=0.00, real=3.74 secs] 
2012-12-07T19:46:49.135-0600: [Full GC [CMS: 752917K->693347K(2804992K), 3.2845870 secs] 752917K->693347K(3111680K), [CMS Perm : 524287K->141759K(524288K)], 3.2846780 secs] [Times: user=3.32 sys=0.00, real=3.29 secs]
```

System info and GC flags:

```
Java 1.7.0_07, 64-Bit Server, Ubuntu 12.04 
-Xms3g -Xmx3g -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

EDIT: we have two app servers; the second one exhibited slightly different behavior: there were only two Full GC entries.

```
2012-12-07T20:36:31.097-0600: [Full GC [CMS: 2307424K->753901K(2804992K), 5.0783720 secs] 2394279K->753901K(3111680K), [CMS Perm : 524280K->524121K(524288K)], 5.0784780 secs] [Times: user=5.12 sys=0.00, real=5.08 secs] 
2012-12-07T20:36:36.178-0600: [Full GC [CMS: 753901K->695698K(2804992K), 3.4488560 secs] 755266K->695698K(3111680K), [CMS Perm : 524121K->140568K(524288K)], 3.4489690 secs] [Times: user=3.48 sys=0.00, real=3.45 secs]
```

So it looks like the young generation was significant. Perhaps it's requiring two successive Full GC, with no other GC (young generation GC) in between to garbage collect perm gen in our particular set up. I've dug a lot, but I haven't found any discussion of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It would not astonish me that the concurrent collections of the heap and perm gen do not influence each other, as especially the heap collection is already a complex operation by itself; that'd explain why the perm gen is only collected the second time. I'm mainly guessing, though.

It might be interesting to get more details on what's actually collected in the perm gen (unloaded classes, strings?). -XX:+PrintGCDetails would help, and maybe -verbose:class.